# jQuery show image on per row basis

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of images. On hover, I need to call a function on the LIs on a per-row basis, which hides all images in that row except the current image. There is only one list.
I have JS to add a data attribute for each of the rows (this is not included in code sample for brevity). How do I hook into the data attribute that is being dynamically set on the rows to call the function that shows and hides the images on a per row basis? Currently, all rows animate.
 
 
**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/2dNgF/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="main">
<div id="add-8" class="row">
<div class="col-lg-11">
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline the-wrap add-8 show-text">
<li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="1"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="2"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>

      <li data-row="3"><img class="full" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/" /> <span class=
      "cover" "><img src=
      "http://i.imgur.com/zK3d6yX.png?1" /></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #main {
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-height: 800px;
    }

    .wrap-the-wrap {
        position: relative;
    }

    .tell-story .hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    ul.the-wrap {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    ul.the-wrap p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul.the-wrap img {
        width: 133px;
        height: auto;
    }

    ul.the-wrap .cover {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -150px;
        left: 0;
    }

    ul.the-wrap .more {
        width: 37px;
        height: 36px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -15px;
        left: 0;

    }

    ul.the-wrap li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    ul.the-wrap .text {
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 150px;
        top: 30px;
        z-index: 1;
        display: none;
        color: #333;
    }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".add-8 li", function () {
        $(this).find(".cover").addClass('current');
        animateCover("-30px");
        $(this).find(".text").fadeIn("fast");
    });

    //covers image with white image
    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".add-8 li", function () {
        $(this).find(".cover").removeClass('current');
        animateCover("-150px");
        $(this).find(".text").fadeOut("fast");
    })

    function animateCover(pos) {
        $("li .cover")
                .not(".current")
                .stop()
                .animate({"bottom": pos}, 250);
    }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question you asked seconds ago. Maybe a double post mistake


Comment: I deleted the double post, please don't close this one.

Comment: @ScottSimpson you need to share the details about the data attribute also

Comment: In regard to the Data Attribute -- I have a way to add that, but I didn't include to keep the code example simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Adding as a different answer since the script is already big*

With a data attribute

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".add-8 li", function () {
    var $this = $(this), rowId = $this.attr('data-row');

    $this.find(".cover").addClass('current');
    animateCover($this.siblings('[data-row="' + rowId + '"]'), "-30px");
    $this.find(".text").fadeIn("fast");
});

//covers image with white image
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".add-8 li", function () {
    var $this = $(this), rowId = $this.attr('data-row');

    $this.find(".cover").removeClass('current');
    animateCover($this.siblings('[data-row="' + rowId + '"]'), "-150px");
    $this.find(".text").fadeOut("fast");
})



$(window).resize(assignRowIds);
assignRowIds();

function assignRowIds(){
    var $els = $('.add-8 li'), row = 0, top;
    $els.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), eltop = $this.offset().top;

        if(eltop != top){
            row++;
            top = eltop;
        }

        $this.attr('data-row', row)
    })
}

function animateCover($rowels, pos) {
    $rowels.find('.cover')
    .not(".current")
    .stop()
    .animate({"bottom": pos}, 250);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rPTHR/)

Answer (score 1):

A solution without the data attribute you said

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".add-8 li", function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.find(".cover").addClass('current');
    animateCover(rowEls(this), "-30px");
    $this.find(".text").fadeIn("fast");
});

//covers image with white image
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".add-8 li", function () {
    $(this).find(".cover").removeClass('current');
    animateCover(rowEls(this), "-150px");
    $(this).find(".text").fadeOut("fast");
})

function rowEls(el){
    var $this = $(el), top = $this.offset().top;

    return $this.parent().children().filter(function(){
        return $(this).offset().top == top;
    })
}

function animateCover($rowels, pos) {
    $rowels.find('.cover')
    .not(".current")
    .stop()
    .animate({"bottom": pos}, 250);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QEFhX/)